# How to solve congruence like these?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So i have three weird congruence that i don't know how to start:

1. $2021^{2021}-2021^{101}≡? \quad (mod \quad 600)$
2. $46^{47^{48}}≡? \quad (mod \quad 25)$
3. $39^{1200}≡? \quad (mod \quad 26)$

I know that i have to use euler-fermat formula, but i don't know how to start.
All i did was to check *a* and *m* are relative prime numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You'll want Euler totient's function. $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod {n}$ and probably iterate it

Comment: @TurlocTheRed - However, (3) looks like a trick question. Also, Carmichael's function is generally more useful than Euler's in this kind of problem.

Comment: Apply [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) as in the dupe. Hints: (with $\lambda$ = Carmichael lambda)
$\begin{align} \\ &(1)\ \  \lambda(600=8\cdot 3\cdot 25)={\rm lcm}(4,2,20)=20,\ \ {\rm so}\ \ 2021^{1+20k} \equiv 2021\!\!\!\pmod{600}\\[.2em]
&(2)\ \bmod \phi(25)\!=\!20\!:\ 47^{4k}\equiv 1\ {\rm by}\ \lambda(4\cdot 5)={\rm lcm}(2,4)=4;\ {\rm or\ directly}\  7^4\equiv 1\\[.2em]
&(3)\ 13^{n+1} \bmod 26 = 13(13^n \bmod 2)=13
\end{align}$  $\tag*{}$

Comment: @BillDubuque $(1)$ - Actually $\lambda(8)=2$, not $4$. But the $20$ in LCM makes it irrelevant.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes, of course. Originally I wrote it using Euler $\phi$ but forgot to update it, but it has no effect (even if it were a *proper* multiple of $\lambda$ we can still use it for exponent reduction).